# how to randomly choose the next code segment to run

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to efficiently and randomly choose the next segment of code to run.

I've found that:

```
eval(random.choice(['a == 1','b == 23','#other things'])
```

and

```
code_to_be_run = random.randint(1,3)
if code_to_be_run == 1:
    a == 1
elif code_to_be_run == 2:
    b == 2
else:
    #other things
```

will work, however they arn't the nicest ways to do it.

Comment: You can create functions and store them in a list, then choose one and call it.

Comment: True, however I would like to avoid using eval

Comment: `eval` or `exec` shouldn't be needed, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create functions and store them in a list, then choose one and call it.

```
import random

def foo():
    print('foo')

def bar():
    print('bar')

def baz():
    print('other stuff')

for _ in range(10):
    random.choice([foo, bar, baz])()
```

Output:

```
bar
other stuff
foo
bar
bar
foo
other stuff
other stuff
bar
foo
```